# how to move code history to another file for refactoring in svn

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I have a long file with multiple classes in it that has been in the project for many years.
Each line has history and I am interested in splitting the file into single class files as step one and the refactor the classes and so on.

I am interested in not losing the code history.

if i copy a class from file OriginAll to its new file, it will look like I wrote the class and all the code history will disappear.
It will seem as if the codeset is only a few days old when in fact it is years old with alot of revisions and history of changes and bugs.

How can i refactor correctly using svn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `svn copy` the original file to a new file and remove from each one of them the extra content. Something like:

```
svn copy OriginAll NewFile
```

Then remove, from `OriginAll`, the content that you need to be part only of `NewFile`. Then remove the content left in `OriginAll` from the `NewFile`.

Not having TortoiseSVN to test, but from what I see it is easily done by dragging the file using right click and you will get a context menu to select `SVN Copy`.

Comment: It's a terrible workaround and takes forever. but it works well and i am (almost) happy.